# Importing CVXOPT in canopy python

Tags: python, canopy, cvxopt

I want to import CVXOPT functionalities for use in the Canopy python editor. As far as I know, I have downloaded CVXOPT successfully. My reason for thinking this is that the CVXOPT site says "to test that the installation was successful, go to the examples directory and try one of the examples", and I am able to do this in the command line without any errors.

However, in my python code, when I say

```
from cvxopt import matrix, spmatrix, solvers, mul, div
```

I get an error saying "No module named CVXOPT". I think the problem must be simple but fiddling around for awhile hasn't fixed the problem. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you an windows and using windows editor?

Comment: I'm on a mac. Isn't canopy the editor?

Comment: How did you install cvxopt? You should check if cvxopt in one of the paths in sys.path

Comment: I just used the tar file from here http://cvxopt.org/download/index.html

Comment: I added a path to it in sys.path but it didn't remove the error.

Comment: Have you completed: http://cvxopt.org/install/index.html ?

Comment: I've completed it through the part where you try the chapter 8 example. That works. I haven't built it with ATLAS though. I downloaded XCode but haven't found the instructions they refer to about building CVXOPT.

Comment: Does it look like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot ?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this site for installing package not readily available in Canopy.

https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469690-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line

After downloading CVXOPT, be sure you are logged in to Enthought account and use Canopy terminal to install the package.