# How do I use pytest with virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pytest

I installed `pytest` into a virtual environment (using `virtualenv`) and am running it from that virtual environment, but it is not using the packages that I installed in that virtual environment. Instead, it is using the main system packages. (Using `python -m unittest discover`, I can actually run my tests with the right python and packages, but I want to use the py.test framework.)

Is it possible that py.test is actually not running the pytest inside the virtual environment and I have to specify which pytest to run?

How to I get py.test to use only the python and packages that are in my virtualenv?

Also, since I have several version of Python on my system, how do I tell which Python that Pytest is using? Will it automatically use the Python within my virtual environment, or do I have to specify somehow?

Comment: Did you actually activate the virtualenv you created before installing and running pytest? i.e. `source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Definitely. I use virtualenvwrapper and the currently activated virtualenv shows up on my prompt when it is activated. Also, I can see the current virtualenv's installed packages using pip freeze.

Comment: I got this to work. It just required a terminal restart.

Answer (score 136):

There is a bit of a dance to get this to work:

1. activate your venv : `source venv/bin/activate`
2. install pytest : `pip install pytest`
3. re-activate your venv: `deactivate && source venv/bin/activate`

The reason is that the path to `pytest` is set by the `source`ing the `activate` file only after `pytest` is actually installed in the `venv`. You can't set the path to something before it is installed.

Re-`activate`ing is required for any console entry points installed within your virtual environment.

Comment: Same idea applies with anaconda envs

Comment: Step 3 could also be `hash -r`

Comment: You're my hero. For those using poetry, I had to run `poetry run pip install pytest` and then `poetry run pytest` would work.

Comment: Resource the venv worked for me.

Comment: "You can't set the path to something before it is installed." I though a venv's activate prepends PATH with the whole venv's bin dir and not the exact binaries. So I hardly can understand why reactivating is needed actually while I know it is really needed in the case above.

Comment: Side effects like this with pytest are really disturbing.

Comment: absolute lifesaver, was driving myself insane troubleshooting why my venv wasn't picking up a package that was clearly installed

Answer (score 84):

Inside your environment, you may try

```
python -m pytest
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was obliged to leave the venv (deactivate), remove pytest (pip uninstall pytest), enter the venv (source /my/path/to/venv), and then reinstall pytest (pip install pytest). I don't known exacttly why pip refuse to install pytest in venv (it says it already present).

I hope this helps

Comment: I had pytest in my base env, but not in my venv so when I called `py.test -v` in the venv it was using the pytest _outside_ the venv and not finding my packages. Anyway, just activating the venv and then doing `conda install pytest` worked for me. (pip works too, I assume.)

Comment: It sounds to me like you had `pytest` installed in both global & venv, but the path to `pytest` had not been updated in your terminal. I think removing the global was not necessary; you just needed to re-`source` the activate script after `pytest` was installed in the `venv` (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you're facing issues running pytest within a Python virtual environment on a Debian (or Ubuntu) system, it's possible that the system's global version of pytest is conflicting with your virtual environment. This can happen because the system's version of pytest uses the global Python interpreter, which doesn't have access to Python packages installed in your virtual environment. You can remove that version of pytest with

```
sudo apt remove python3-pytest
```

Then activate your virtual environment and install pytest within the virtual environment with

```
pip intall pytest
```

That way pytest will be able to load the python packages installed in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

you have to activate your python env every time you want to run your python script, you have several ways to activate it, we assume that your virtualenv is installed under /home/venv :

1- the based one is to run the python with one command line 
`>>> /home/venv/bin/python <your python file.py>`

2- add this line on the top of python script file 
`#! /home/venv/bin/python` and then run `python <you python file.py>`

3- activate your python env `source /home/venv/bin/activate` and then run you script like `python <you python file.py>`

4- use [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to manager and activate your python environments

Comment: I definitely always activate my env every time I run any script from it and deactivate it when I am done.

Comment: My active virtualenv is part of my prompt.

I got py.test to use my virtualenv by restarting my terminal.