# Failed to import matplotlib on AppEngine dev server

Tags: google-app-engine, matplotlib, google-app-engine-python

When I'm using AppEngine dev server it fails to import matplotlib although it's installed.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.15
$ pip show matplotlib
Name: matplotlib
Version: 1.2.0
```

The error I'm getting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

I went through the doc page [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#matplotlib), and it says that "experimental" version is not supported.
Which version of matplotlib is considered as experimental? Although I'm using the same version as built-in matplotlib it seems have the same issue. Is it possible to use matplotlib with AppEngine dev server?

Comment: The symptoms are identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27

It looks like there is only 1 version of matplotlib available, so I'd guess it won't work on your local dev server in general.

You could set up an additional `lib` folder called `localhost_libs` and install it to there, like this `pip install -t localhost_libs/ matplotlib`

And then put something like this in your `appengine_config.py`

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')

# If on local dev server
if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Development'):
    vendor.add('localhost_libs')
```