# Python3.7: No module named

Tags: macos, matplotlib, sublimetext3, python-3.7, textblob

I've been trying to install matplotlib and textblob on my system using

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

or

```
pip3 install textblob
```

It says it's installed successfully. However, when I try to import in in Sublime Text it says

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

or

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textblob'
```

I've set up the build system in sublime text for python 3. A lot of modules that I've installed and are using the same way works fine (BeautifulSoup, requests and tweepy for example). I do not understand why some modules work and others do not. I've been trying to find the solution to this problem but after hours of research without results, I see this question as my last resort. Very thankful for all help.

shell_cmd: /usr/bin/env python3

Comment: If you start python terminal type ```help('modules')```, can you see matplotlib and textblob?

Comment: When I type `help('modules')` in terminal, it says `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ''modules'' `. I've however tried to type pip3 list and then I can see both matplotlib and textblob.

Comment: I am just wondering that is it possible that you are having two versions of python installed in your machine. Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot ?

Comment: As I'm using a mac (which comes with python 2), I am having two versions installed. However, I don't think that is a problem as I've set up the build system in sublime text with python 3 and I've installed the modules with pip3 install