# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'interactive'

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When using `%matplotlib inline` in Jupyter  notebook I'm getting error:

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'interactive'

This is the [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11821).

I have also reffered to this issue in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot)
but I could not find the answer.

I tried this :

```
%matplotlib --list
```

and found this :

> Available matplotlib backends: ['tk', 'gtk', 'gtk3', 'wx', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'qt', 'osx', 'nbagg', 'notebook', 'agg', 'svg', 'pdf', 'ps', 'inline', 'ipympl', 'widget']

It shows, that I have `inline` in my matplotlib but couldnot use it.

I have also tried :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

without using `%matplotlib inline` but found this error instead :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'

Then, I tried to install this module in my conda venv and got this error :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMGbQ.png)
please help me out :)

Answer (score 10):

Solution for me was to remove matplot lib from my conda environment which forced dependencies to be removed as well.
After running installation again :

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

all worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I try every command line that i found in all forum. But no one work for me .
Then i use **pip install --upgrade matplotlib** . It's work for me . and solve this issue Jupyter Notebook