# how to import modules like matplotlab in PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, module

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

freq = {c: random.randint(1, 100) for c in alphabet if random.randint(1, 10) > 2}
print(len(freq))
print(freq)

plt.bar(range(len(freq)), freq.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(freq)), freq.keys())
plt.show()
```

I received a code which uses matplotlib, I already installed it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot) in console (in Git Bash) and searched for matplotlib under settings - modules, but found just two other and installed them (aliasimports/live coding in python). I still become this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: in your pycharm output console, you can see the python location(`C:\some\path\Scripts\python.exe`), now, run `the python.full.path.exe -m pip install matplotlib`

Comment: @LeiYang I said, I did it already.

Comment: when I try your suggestion, I see that: "Requirement already satisfied"

Comment: you didn't do, i promise.

Comment: @LeiYang I tried and it doesn't helped

Comment: `print(sys.executable)` print what?

Comment: @LeiYang the solution by Ahmed helped me, still many thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pycharm File -> View -> Tools Windows -> Python packages
It will list all installed packages, search for Matplotlib and install it.

If you are running in terminal:

```
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

If on unix:
locate your python, which python

```
python_path/bin/python -m pip install matplotlib
```

If you are using python2, without pip. Install it

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

After saving above file, run

```
python get-pip.py
```

Now run pip install command.

If your script is using shebang, do include this line at top of your file

```
#!/path/to/your/path/binary
```

Comment: The first sentence already helped me, thanks!
A little edited path:
"Pycharm -> View -> Tool Windows -> Python packages: It will list all installed packages, search for Matplotlib and install it"

Answer (score 0):

before using any library in python you need to install it. for installation there are different methods(depend on OS) but simple way is `PIP INSTALL PKG_NAME`