# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' through terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, terminal, pycharm

I have cw2.py on pycharm

when I type this code into my terminal I get the  following error but matplotlib is installed in pycharm and has worked.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

python3 cw2.py -d 140218233015-c848da298ed6d38b98e18a85731a83f4 -t 2a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\cw2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import program
  File "C:\Users\A\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\program.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot)

Comment: It's confusing, I have windows and I don't have  pip and I could not find a way to install it.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command