# Module Not Found matplotlib in VSCODE Mac OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
khalidali@Khalids-MacBook-Pro lab4 % /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/khalidali/Desktop/CSE 107/lab4/test_HistogramEqualization.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/khalidali/Desktop/CSE 107/lab4/test_HistogramEqualization.py", line 33, in <module>
    plot_histogram( dark_hist )
  File "/Users/khalidali/Desktop/CSE 107/lab4/My_HE_functions.py", line 51, in plot_histogram
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I installed Matplotlib using `pip3 install matplotlib`

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip install matplotlib`. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot) also has the exact same issue if you want to take a look at other solutions posted there.

Comment: Or even try `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot)

Comment: If your script is executed by `/usr/local/bin/python3`, then the script will find ONLY the modules that had been installed by `pip`, as run by `/usr/local/bin/python3`.  In other words, the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74394548/module-not-found-matplotlib-in-vscode-mac-os#comment131333323_74394548) by @wjandrea seems really on spot.